# Putting back gnome-shell option on login screen

Tags: 11.04, login-screen, gnome

For some reason gnome-shell login option does not show anymore in the login screen. How may i add it back?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you do to make it disappear? Can you add some useful details to your question?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on 11.04 and using the gnome3 team ppa, I believe it is just called Gnome now and that will log you into gnome-shell.